# Identifying objects, shapes in a image and recognizing them using UITouch in iOS?

Tags: ios, image, encoding, uitouch, decoding

The app I create has a set of images. The images will have flow charts. The chart will have different nodes and arrows indicating the flows between them and nodes will have titles with them.

Now when user clicks on the Node (say titled Start Operation), I need to capture this event with the information of the title of the node and other node information.

I think this is not possible unless I store some information in the image when it is created and when user taps on the image, I can capture the location of touch and try extracting the information encoded.

What are your suggestions on this?

Comment: My suggestion forget image, do everything in code.

Comment: I am not going to a have a single image. I might have several images coming from servers. I can not create all of them in code..

Comment: I saw a solution similar to what I expect in this tutorial http://abitofcode.com/2011/07/irregular-touch-detection-when-cgrect-is-not-enough-part-1/#comments